# Redirect multilevel subdomain to a folder .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain **meet.example.com** that points to the **app** folder and I want **api.meet.example.com** to point to the **api** folder.

The folder structure is like this

**public_html** - root folder

- app
- api

Then this is the rule that I have in my **.htaccess** I have in the root folder. The first rule works fine and opens the content from the app folder, but the second rule (api.meet.example.com)  is not opening the content from the api folder.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meet\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/
RewriteRule (.*) /app/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.meet.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
RewriteRule (.*) /api/$1 [L]
```

What I am doing wrong here?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks for @anubhava question about the `VirtualHost` config I just realized that I did redirect both domains from one hosting to another, but didn't add both domains to the new hosting just the **meet.example.com**, assuming that as **api.meet.example.com** is actually a subdomain of the already added then I will not need to add it.

Adding **api.meet.example.com** as a domain to the new hosting fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you share your `VirtualHost` config to show how these 2 sites are defined.

Comment: Basically, the subdomain (meet.example.com) is redirected from one hosting and added as the main domain in the other. One thing I am thinking now when I am writing this... Should I actually redirect the api.meet.example.com to the new hosting as well, as it is a subdomain of the already redirected meet.example.com?

Comment: @anubhava, based on your comment I figure it out. Edited my question with the solution

Comment: Happy to note that you were able to solve the problem.